# Compiler Requiring Return Value - Not Noticing Unconditional Exception in Called Method

Tags: c#, exception, compiler-construction

Why c# compiler is not smart enough in the following scenario?

```
    void ThrowEx() {
        throw new Exception();
    }

    int Test() {
        ThrowEx();
    }
```

...Test()': not all code paths return a value

**Edit:** in practice, i want to extract exception throwing logic into a separate method because i'm tired typing stuff like `throw new FaultException<MyCustomFault>(new MyCustomFault(), "cannot validate the input");`

Comment: How much analysis do you want the compiler to do? How deep should it go?

Comment: Why would you want this?

Comment: The simple answer is that it's a compiler not an interpreter

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it. By programming language semantic, the method should return an int value.

Comment: This would be the first time that I've ever encountered someone trying to use generic exceptions.  Why are you doing that instead of hoisting a concrete class (so you can catch MyCustomFaultExceptions)?

Comment: @John - imho, the compiler does much more analysis resolving, for example, generics that this case

Comment: @48klocs - WCF forces me to do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look between methods; not least, the method could be in a different assembly and could change without rebuilds, or could be virtual, extern, abstract or partial - it would be confusing to spot only a small number of cases.

You could have the ThrowEx return "int", and then:

```
return ThrowEx();
```

which would make the compiler happy. Or use generics:

```
static T ThrowEx<T>() {...}
...
return ThrowEx<int>();
```

Comment: The problem with generics is that i can't put "void" instead of T

Comment: Good point about different assembly although in my case it's within the same class, i.e. no excuse for the translator.

Comment: @UserControl - just call and discard: ThrowEx<int>();

Comment: @UserControl - or a second overload - i.e. your current ThrowEx

Comment: i'd vote for original verbose "throw new" versus cryptic/unnatural return ThrowEx<sometype>() :(

Answer (score 2):

ThrowEx() is void. The compiler knows this, and it determines that there is no return value for the Test() method. The compiler is designed to test your successful method production. Injecting a thrown exception as a valid response is not a reasonable compiler expectation.

Answer (score 1):

And how do you wish the **compiler** to handle cases such as

```
void ThrowEx() { 
    decimal i = ... get 1 from app config;
    decimal div = ... get 0 from app confid
    decimal randomNumber = i / div;
    do some other stuff....
} 

int Test() { 
    ThrowEx(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Among other things, the Debugger or Profiler API could allow throwing the exception in ThrowEx to be skipped, at which point the behavior of Test would be undefined.